# Is there a name for the common class of instrument which Spots and Forwards belong to?

Tags: forward, spot-rate

I'm doing some database design where I'm modelling Forwards and Spots. They share the same schema, the only difference is that Spots have a settlement date of the time they were created at, while Forwards have a settlement date some time in the future.

I know it seems banal, but they're really similar in structure, and I'm struggling to come up with a name for my common class that isn't `ForwardAndSpotCommon`.

Comment: I am not sure there is an accepted word, perhaps DeliveryContract qould do?

Comment: Or how about ‘delta-one’. A commonly used equity term for anything that does not need a volatility input

Comment: Generally spot is by definition delta1. However, in my understanding, delta1  excludes spot in definitions. Bloomberg defines them as cash (as in "A contract to either pay another party cash or receive cash from another party on the specified delivery date") within OVML. I am not sure of the purpose of mingling them together though? You could lump forward into derivatives, would make more sense (imho).